# Как на Java проверить, что папка смонтирована и доступна?

Tags: java-ee, java, сеть, linux

На сервере монтируется папка следующим образом:

```
root@ubuntusrv:/mnt# mount -t cifs //192.168.14.12/share -o auto,user,iocharset=utf8,uid=1001,umask=000,username=john,password=smith /mnt/target
```

или так:

```
root@ubuntusrv:/mnt# mount -t cifs //192.168.14.12/share -o username=john,password=smith /mnt/target
```

Как в веб приложении на Java проверить, что папка /mnt/target смонтирована и доступна?

Comment: так пробовали: new File().exists() ?

Comment: и??? монтируемая папка будит всегда, даже если не смонтирована, проверять в шаре какой либо файл заведомо не правельно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наверное проще всего прочесть файлы из /mnt/target, если не пусто, то смонтирована.

Но вот с NFS и autumount (а может и самбой тоже?) есть проблема, что в случае недоступности сервера Ваш процесс подвисает (что самое неприятное в UNINTERRUPTABLE).

Еще можно вызвать mount и проанализировать его вывод

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount");
....
```

но тут (с автомаунтом) другая засада, сервер может быть и доступен, а в выводе mount /mnt/target нет, т.к. никто пока еще туда не заходил.

А задача не только для Java, на всех языках решение примерно одинаковое.

Comment: А при монтировании сетевого ресурса не появляется запись в /etc/mtab ?

Comment: @mikillskegg, появляется, но у меня, например, не сразу(???). Тоже после первого обращения. 

    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/dispro$ cat /etc/fstab
    ....
    manager01:   /soft /mnt/soft nfs  rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
    #storage:    /soft  /mnt/hpcsoft     nfs  rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/dispro$ cat /etc/mtab
    /dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
    ....
    manager01:/soft /mnt/soft nfs rw,r  size=8192,wsize=8192,intr,vers=4,addr=10.1.2.3,clientaddr=0.0.0.0 0 0
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/dispro$ 


Обратил внимание, когда как-то подвис.

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/ думаю сильно поможет.